# Service Worker "notificationclick" not firing

Tags: web-notifications

The notification is showing fine, but when I click on it, or any of the actions, nothing happens. I see no logging, no error messages, but the notification does close (although it closes even when I comment out the `event.notification.close()`).

I've tried using the Chrome debugger, and I can set a break point in the code that shows the notification, but all breakpoints within the `notificationclick` handler fail to pause execution.

I've spent days trying to get this to work and I'm at my wits' end.

```js
const auth = firebase.auth();
const functions = firebase.functions();
const done = functions.httpsCallable("done");
const snooze = functions.httpsCallable("snooze");

self.addEventListener("notificationclick", event => {
  console.log("notificationclick", event);
  const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
  const { id, url } = event.notification.data;

  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(() => {
    switch (event.action) {
      case "done":
        console.log("Done");
        return done({ uid, id });
      case "snooze1":
        console.log("Snooze 1 Hour");
        return snooze({ uid, id, hours: 1 });
      case "snooze24":
        console.log("Snooze 1 Day");
        return snooze({ uid, id, hours: 24 });
      default:
        console.log("Open App");
        return clients
          .matchAll({
            includeUncontrolled: true,
            type: "window"
          })
          .then(clientList => {
            for (let i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
              let client = clientList[i];
              if (url[0] === "#") {
                if (client.url.endsWith(url) && "focus" in client) {
                  return client.focus();
                }
              } else {
                if (
                  client.url.replace(/#.*$/, "") === url &&
                  "focus" in client
                ) {
                  return client.focus();
                }
              }
            }
            if (clients.openWindow) {
              return clients.openWindow(location.origin + url);
            }
          });
    }
  });
});

firebase
  .messaging()
  .setBackgroundMessageHandler(({ data: { title, options } }) => {
    options = JSON.parse(options);
    options.actions = [
      { action: "done", title: "Done" },
      { action: "snooze1", title: "Snooze 1 Hour" },
      { action: "snooze24", title: "Snooze 1 Day" }
    ];

    return self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Could you try below code and see if this is getting called-

```
 self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
        event.notification.close();
        var redirectUrl = null;
        var tag = event.notification.tag;
        if (event.action) {
            redirectUrl = event.action
        } 
        if (redirectUrl) {
            event.waitUntil(async function () {
                var allClients = await clients.matchAll({
                    includeUncontrolled: !0
                });
                var chatClient;
                for (const client of allClients) {
                    if (redirectUrl != '/' && client.url.indexOf(redirectUrl) >= 0) {
                        client.focus();
                        chatClient = client;
                        break
                    }
                }
                if (chatClient == null || chatClient == 'undefined') {
                    chatClient = clients.openWindow(redirectUrl);
                    return chatClient
                }
            }().then(result => {
                if (tag) {
                    //PostAction(tag, "click")
                }
            }))
        }
    });
```

Edited-
Attaching both js files. it is working at my end.

```
firebase-messaging-sw.js
```

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');
var config = {
    apiKey: "your api key",
    authDomain: "you firebase domain",
    databaseURL: "your firbase db url",
    projectId: "your project id",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "sender id"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload.data);    
    var notificationTitle = payload.data.Title;
    var notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.data.Body,
        icon: payload.data.Icon,
        image: payload.data.Image,
        action: payload.data.ClickAction
    };
    console.log("strated sending msg" + notificationOptions);
    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,notificationOptions);
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    console.log('On notification click: ', event.notification);
    event.notification.close();
    var redirectUrl = null;
    if (event.notification.data) {
        if (event.notification.data.FCM_MSG) {
            redirectUrl = event.notification.data.FCM_MSG.data ? event.notification.data.FCM_MSG.data.click_action : null
        } else {  
            redirectUrl = event.notification.data ? event.notification.data.click_action : null
        }
    }
    console.log("redirect url is : " + redirectUrl);

    if (redirectUrl) {       
        event.waitUntil(async function () {
            var allClients = await clients.matchAll({
                includeUncontrolled: true
            });
            var chatClient;            
            for (var i = 0; i < allClients.length; i++) {
                var client = allClients[i];                
                if (client['url'].indexOf(redirectUrl) >= 0) {
                    client.focus();
                    chatClient = client;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (chatClient == null || chatClient == 'undefined') {
                chatClient = clients.openWindow(redirectUrl);
                return chatClient;
            }
        }());        
    }
});

self.addEventListener("notificationclose", function (event) {
    event.notification.close();
    console.log('user has clicked notification close');    
});
```

`application.js` file :

```js
/// <reference path="scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js" />

try {
var config = {
    apiKey: "your api key",
    authDomain: "you firebase domain",
    databaseURL: "your firbase db url",
    projectId: "your project id",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "sender id"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
    console.log('Service Worker and Push is supported');

    navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
        .then((swReg) => {
            firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker(swReg);
            askForPermissioToReceiveNotifications();            
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
            window.alert("Service Worker Error" + error);
        })
} else {
        console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');        
        window.alert("Push messaging is not supported " + (navigator.serviceWorker));    
}

const askForPermissioToReceiveNotifications = async () => {
    try {                    
                    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
                    console.log(messaging);
                    await messaging.requestPermission();
                    const token = await messaging.getToken();                    
                    if (token !== null || token !== 'undefined') {
                        await sendDeviceTokenToServerSide(token);
                    }                    
                    console.log('Got token : ' + token);
                    messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
                        console.log('onMessage: ', payload);
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (registration) { 
                                var notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
                                var notificationOptions = {
                                    body: payload.notification.body,
                                    data: payload.data,
                                    icon: payload.notification.icon,
                                    image: payload.data.Image,
                                    requireInteraction: payload.notification.requireInteraction,
                                    tag: payload.notification.tag,
                                    click_action: payload.data.click_action,
                                    requireInteraction: true
                                };
                                registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
                            },50)
                        });                                                
                    }); 
    }
    catch (e) { console.log('error in getting token: ' + e); window.alert("error in getting token: " + e); } 
 }

function sendDeviceTokenToServerSide(token) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/StoreToken',
            timeout: 5000000,           
            data: { token: token },
            success: function (success) {                
                console.log("device token is sent to server");                                
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("device error sending token to server : " + error);
                window.alert("device error sending token to server : " + error);
            }
        });
}
} catch (e) {
    window.alert("error: " + e);
}

function GetFcmUserToken(messaging) {
    messaging.onTokenRefresh(function () {
        messaging.getToken()
            .then(function (refreshedToken) {
                console.log('Token refreshed.');               
                return refreshedToken;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
                showToken('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
            });
    });
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior with your code as I did with mine.

Comment: and your code is under serviceworker.js/firebase-messaging-sw.js right ?

Comment: Yep, the rest of the code in the file is working. I just can't get the click handler to fire.

Comment: this is happening when website is in foreground and background both or just on background case ?

Comment: The notification only appears when the website is in the background. I think this behavior is handled by Firebase messaging.

Comment: nope. notification can appear when website is in foreground as well. you can have `push` event for that.

Comment: I'm not sure what difference it makes, but I don't need to receive push notifications when the app is in FG because they're triggered by data already synced with the app. So I only care about BG notifications and am not handling them when in FG.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
const clickedNotification = event.notification;
// Do something as the result of the notification click
const promiseChain = clients.openWindow(clickedNotification.data.Url);
event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
});
```

This code inside service worker js worked fine for me on chrome Desktop and Android.